# FBML is not rendered in Facebook App in iframe - please help

Tags: php, facebook, fbml, facebook-fbml, serverfbml

I'm developing an Facebook Application in PHP. It's loaded as an iframe and not as FBML. The normal interaction with Facebook works. For example the following code gives the username:

```
$facebook = new Facebook($config->appapikey, $config->appsecret);
$user_id = $facebook->require_login($required_permissions = 'email');
echo $user->name;
```

Where $user is my class in which the user-details are loaded from facebook.
My document begins the following way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head><title>Appname</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php/de_DE" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And ends likes this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
FB_RequireFeatures(['XFBML','CanvasUtil'], function(){ 
FB.init("<?php echo $config->appapikey; ?>", "/app/xd_receiver.htm");
FB.CanvasClient.startTimerToSizeToContent(); 
 });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also the file xd_receiver.htm is loaded as I can see in Firebug.

But my problem is that for example the request-form is not loaded. My code:

```
<fb:serverFbml>
    <script type="text/fbml"> 
        <fb:fbml>
            <fb:request-form method="post" action="<?php echo $config->site; ?>index.php" type="appname" invite="true" target="_top" content="content">
                <fb:multi-friend-selector actiontext="text" rows="3" showborder="true" target="_top"/>
            </fb:request-form>
        </fb:fbml>
    </script>
</fb:serverFbml>
```

I can see the code with Firebug but the form ist not displayed by Facebook.

2 or 3 weeks ago it was displayed but in this time I had the tags

```
    </fb:fbml>
</script>
</fb:serverFbml>
```

arround my complete text in the body. 2 weeks ago I had the the problem that nothing any more was displayed. After I removed the tags my app is displayed but not the form.

I am searchign the web vor 1 week now and read many Threads about FBML and XFBML in Facebook but nothing worked for me.

So thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I'm not sure what to say.  I just looked over all your code and everything looks to be in place.  Maybe try adding this

```
FB.XFBML.Host.autoParseDomTree = true;
```

Right after the call to `FB.init()`

Comment: Thank your for your answer but also with your code nothing changed.

At another point in my app I am trying to show a form to the user for posting on it's wall. This also functioned in the past but is not any more.
my code:

     function publish() {
     var action_links = [{'text':'appame','href':'link'}];
     var message='message';
     FB_RequireFeatures(["Connect"], function() {
     FB.init('appid', 'xd_receiver.htm');
     FB.ensureInit(function() {
     FB.Connect.streamPublish(message, null, action_links, null);
     });
     });
     }
     window.onload = publish;